# Unable to delete SharePoint Online sub-site with SP hosted app installed

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, sharepoint-hosted-app, sub-site

When i try to delete a site(Site Settings -> Delete the Site) with SP hosted app installed in the respective site, we are getting the below error

### There was a problem deleting Web site "". Sites that have subsites or certain apps can't be deleted. Please try again after deleting all subsites and removing the apps.

Is this the normal functionality or a solution to delete the site normally without uninstalling the app.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You have to first delete all subsites created within the certain site you want to delete.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint, one can not delete a web site which has an active sub site. Since, SP hosted app is also technically created as a subsite inside the site where it is activated (Url is different by storage location is inside activating website), the website can not be deleted without uninstalling/deleting the app.